# Concatenate a string to the whole dataframe column

Tags: r, dataframe, append, string-concatenation

I have a data frame and want to append some text with all the elements of it.

For example

My Data frame

```
1
2
3
4
```

I want the resulting data frame as

```
number 1
number 2
number 3
number 4
```

So the "number" string is in common which I have to append with each elements of the dataframe. I am writing a for loop to iterate through the data frame but I do not know how to append "number" in each row.

Comment: Try `df1$myCol <- paste("number", df1$myCol)`

Comment: No that did not help.The dataframe is now coming like **number(1,2,3,4)**

Comment: [How to make a great R reproducible example?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

Comment: Try this toy example: `df1 <- data.frame(myCol = 1:4)` then run above code. It should work, if it didn't then please provide dummy dataframe of your own that is representative of your real data.

Comment: Yes it works perfectly.Thanks a lot.

Comment: @zx8754 If I want to append something like number"one" 1 what can I do?I tried df1$myCol <- paste("number"one"", df1$myCol) and df1$myCol <- paste("number\"one"\", df1$myCol).Both did not work.

Comment: Please edit your post.